# Integral estimation of the number of zeros of an function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let be $f : [a, b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a continuously differentiable function.

We suppose that:

- $f(a)f(b) < 0$
- $\lvert f \rvert + \lvert f' \rvert > 0$

Let us denote $I(\varepsilon) = \dfrac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int\limits_a^b \lvert f' \rvert 1_{\lvert f \rvert < \varepsilon}$ where $1_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.

I would like to show that $I(\varepsilon) \to \mathrm{card } f^{-1}(0)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

What I have done so far:

- I have proved there was a finite amount of zeros using the hypothesis as all zeros were isolated points.
- I found a certain set of $\varepsilon$ where $f^{-1}(]-\varepsilon, \varepsilon[)$ is a finite reunion of open intervals.
- I can upper bound my integral by the limit desired, using the finite reunion of open intervals.

I would like to show something like the integral would be strictly decreasing or get a lower bound and squeeze theorem. I tried to use uniform convergence to get precise estimates but failed to get further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the hardest part of the problem.

As you said the second condition :

- $\mid f \mid + \mid f' \mid > 0$

Means that all the zero are isolated points, which means that if : $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$ then there is an $\epsilon$, such that $\forall x \in ]c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon[, f(x) \ne 0$.

Moreover the first condition is also very important. $f(a)f(b) < 0$, means that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have different signs.

So using the fact that $f$, is continuous we have by the intermediate value theorem a point $c'$ where $f(c') = 0$.

Now, let $n$ be the number of annulation points of the function $f$, as we said earlier $n$ is such that : $0 < n < \infty$ and let's denote : $r_1 < r_2 < ... < r_n$ the roots of $f$.

Using the fact that $r_i$ are isolated points, we can find a couple $(z_i, z'_i) \in [a,b]^2, z_i \ne z'_i$ such that $\mid f(r_i-z_i)\mid =  \mid f(z'_i+r_i) \mid = \epsilon  $ and for all $i \leq n$ :

$$\forall x \in [r_i-z_i, r_i+z'_i], \mid f(x) \mid \leq \epsilon $$

Moreover $f$ is continuous so on the compact sets : $[r_i, r_{i+1}]$, $f$ has a supremum. Hence if we take $\epsilon$ such that : $\epsilon < \min \{ \sup_{[r_{i-1}, r_{i}]} f, \sup_{[r_{i}, r_{i+1}]} f \}$ then we have :

$$\int_a^b \mid f' \mid \mathbb{1}_{\mid f \mid < \epsilon} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{r_i-z_i}^{r_i+z'_i} \mid f'(x) \mid \mathrm{d}x$$

Hence : 
$$\int_{r_i-z_i}^{r_i+z'_i} \mid f'(x) \mid \mathrm{d}x = \mid f(r_i+z'_i)+f(r_i-z_i) \mid = 2\epsilon$$

So finally we get : 
$$I(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{r_i-z_i}^{r_i+z'_i} \mid f'(x) \mid \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\cdot n \cdot 2\epsilon = n = \mid f^{-1}(\{0\}) \mid$$

You can note that here I am not taking the limit but just assuming that  : 
$\epsilon < \min \{ \sup_{[r_{i-1}, r_{i}]} f, \sup_{[r_{i}, r_{i+1}]} f \}$, and your equality is always true when this happend (so especially when $\epsilon \to 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $|f'|$ is positive near a zero of $f$, all zeros are isolated.

Assume $f$ has countably infinite many zeros, say $x_k$ for $k\in \mathbb N$. Then, as $[a, b]$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence with limit $x^*$. By continuity, $x^*$ is a zero but not isolated. That's a contradiction.

Let $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ denote the zeros of $f$. Then, for each $k=1,\dotsc,n$ by continuity of $f'$ there exists some $\delta_k > 0$ such that $|f'|$ is positive on $(x_k - \delta_k, x_k + \delta_k)$. Now, let
$$ \epsilon = \min_{1\le k \le n} \min \{ |f(x_k - \delta_k)|, |f(x_k + \delta_k)|\}.$$

For that $\epsilon$, $N_\epsilon = f^{-1}((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$ is partitioned into $n$ disjointed open intervals such that $f$ is injective on $I_k$ and $f(I_k) = (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.
Integrate by substitution yields
$$ I(\epsilon) = \frac1{2\epsilon} \int_{N_\epsilon} |f'| = \frac1{2\epsilon} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{I_k} |f'| = \frac1{2\epsilon} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} 1 = n.$$

Comment: Do you have an example of a function with countably infinite many zeros which verify the hypothesis? I believed that through compactness of the set of zeros and isolation, there could be no injective sequence of zeros. But very nice answer.

Comment: @Raito my bad, there are only finitely many zeros. I edited my answer.